# How would a web app get a users roles for an api?

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

I have an API running using Azure AD authentication, with three roles (Admin/Manager/Viewer). On the API side of things, this all works fine, when a request comes in, the roles are all set correctly.

Now I'm building a website that communicates with this API (Currently Blazor server side, but could just as easily be an MVC site). The user logs into this site, and when they perform an action I'm using the On-Behalf-Of flow to acquire a token and call the API.

What is the best way for the website to know what roles the user has on the API? This would be used to hide/disable certain pages.

I see two ways right now:

- Duplicate the roles so the web app has the same roles setup, worst case if the web app is missing one, they'll just get an error when executing a protected action
- Expose an method on the api to return the users roles from the token and have the web app call this when a user logs in

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Store roles inside your token in case of jwt  , and extract it from it. But better to make token short living in case of you update the roles.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this, once the user logs in, I can acquire an access token for the api and then use the JwtSecurityTokenHandler to read it into a JwtToken and access the claims there.

```
var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenOnBehalfOfUser(this._contextAccessor.HttpContext, new[] { _scope });
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var jwt = handler.ReadJwtToken(accessToken);
//jwt.Claims - get roles from claims
```